# No such module Swift Package

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11, swift-package-manager

**I have 2 packages inside the app,**

> 1. MSExtension -> Contains some func related to the view controller, views, and labels, etc...
> 2. CustomUIpackage -> Standard custom UI like Button, label, and Radio buttons

CustomUIPackage has a dependency on the MSExtension, for the purpose of accessing some common functionalities of Button and Label,

So I have imported **MSExtension** into the **CustomUIPackage** and **App**.
If I build and Run for the simulator it is working as expected, I am able to build and execute the app.

I am able to build the project for simulator as well as generic iOS device But When I try to archive the project getting error as

> No such module MSExtension

The error is in the *CusomUIPackage* where *MSExpension* package is imported

[image: importing a package inside other package]

Is there any other way Better way I can achieve this?. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I was following this tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xu9oeCAS8aA.
With single dependency, we don't need any target we can archive. I have just created a package and In general settings I embed them.

Answer (score 2):

After Reading about swift package manager and adding the dependency from [link](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/managing-dependencies-using-the-swift-package-manager/)

I changed the Package.swift by adding the dependency list and its path. I was able to archive the app.

### Before, Not specifying the dependency for the swift package manager.

```
 
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MSUIElements",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries produced by a package, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "MSUIElements",
            targets: ["MSUIElements"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
        // No depency path added
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "MSUIElements",
            dependencies: []),      // dependcy name not mentioned
        .testTarget(
            name: "MSUIElementsTests",
            dependencies: ["MSUIElements"]),
    ]
)
```

After

```
 
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MSUIElements",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries produced by a package, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "MSUIElements",
            targets: ["MSUIElements"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
    .package(path:"../MSExtension")
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "MSUIElements",
            dependencies: ["MSExtension"]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MSUIElementsTests",
            dependencies: ["MSUIElements"]),
    ]
)
```